# scons build both static and shared library

Tags: scons

I am trying to build both a static and a shared library using the same sources with SCons.

Everything works fine if I just build one or the other, but as soon as I try to build both, only the static library is built.

My SConscript looks like:

```
cppflags = SP3_env['CPPFLAGS']
cppflags += ' -fPIC '
SP3_env['CPPFLAGS'] = cppflags

soLibFile = SP3_env.SharedLibrary(
   target = "sp3",
   source = sources)
installedSoFile = SP3_env.Install(SP3_env['SP3_lib_dir'], soLibFile)

libFile = SP3_env.Library(
    target = "sp3",
    source = sources)
installedLibFile = SP3_env.Install(SP3_env['SP3_lib_dir'], libFile)
```

I also tried SharedObject(sources) before the SharedLibrary (passing in the return from SharedObject, rather than sources), but it is no different.  Same if I build the .a before the .so.

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 6):

When the installation directory is **not** in or below the current directory, SCons does not behave as expected, as commented in the [SCons Install method docs:](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c2938.html)

> Note, however, that installing a file is still considered a type of
>   file "build." This is important when you remember that the default
>   behavior of SCons is to build files in or below the current directory.
>   If, as in the example above, you are installing files in a directory
>   outside of the top-level SConstruct file's directory tree, you must
>   specify that directory (or a higher directory, such as /) for it to
>   install anything there:

That is, you must invoke SCons with the install directory as a target (`SP3_env['SP3_lib_dir']` in your case) in order for the installation to be executed. To simplify this, use `env.Alias()` as I do below.

When you invoke SCons, you should at least see that both the static and shared libraries are built in the local project dir. I would imagine, however, that SCons does not install them. Here is an example I made on Ubuntu that works:

```
env = Environment()

sourceFiles = 'ExampleClass.cc'

sharedLib = env.SharedLibrary(target='example', source=sourceFiles)
staticLib = env.StaticLibrary(target='example', source=sourceFiles)

# Notice that installDir is outside of the local project dir
installDir = '/home/notroot/projects/sandbox'

sharedInstall = env.Install(installDir, sharedLib)
staticInstall = env.Install(installDir, staticLib)

env.Alias('install', installDir)
```

If I execute scons with no targets, I get the following:

```
# scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o ExampleClass.o -c ExampleClass.cc
g++ -o ExampleClass.os -c -fPIC ExampleClass.cc
ar rc libexample.a ExampleClass.o
ranlib libexample.a
g++ -o libexample.so -shared ExampleClass.os
scons: done building targets.
```

Then I can install, executing scons with the install target, as follows:

```
# scons install
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
Install file: "libexample.a" as "/home/notroot/projects/sandbox/libexample.a"
Install file: "libexample.so" as "/home/notroot/projects/sandbox/libexample.so"
scons: done building targets.
```

Or, you could just do it all with one command, first clean everything

```
# scons -c install
```

Then, do it all with just one command:

```
# scons install
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o ExampleClass.o -c ExampleClass.cc
g++ -o ExampleClass.os -c -fPIC ExampleClass.cc
ar rc libexample.a ExampleClass.o
ranlib libexample.a
g++ -o libexample.so -shared ExampleClass.os
Install file: "libexample.a" as "/home/notroot/projects/sandbox/libexample.a"
Install file: "libexample.so" as "/home/notroot/projects/sandbox/libexample.so"
scons: done building targets.
```